# how to recover my HDD partitions by ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

Actually what I did,is I was trying to install Ubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately I selected 3rd option "Erase disk and install ubuntu with LVM option. It remapped my 3 partitions of HDD

**#1 Ubuntu OS (100GB)

  #2 Linux swap (2GB)

  #3 My data (800GB)**

and showing some 3 partitions of unknown type with different partition size.Then and then I quited the installation, nothing at all installed and not even formatted the HDD physically.

But now whenever I am running my previous Ubuntu 14.04 it showing GRUB2 error and even while I am running live cd of ubuntu, it is showing me different partitions of my HDD. Though I know that physically all the data and partition is still remain there in HDD.

**Now I want to know is their any way to recover those partitions or just the data stored in partition #3. because those are very important to me.**

Please any one help me. **Thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use [SystemRescueCd](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) for your problem.Go through the documentation of it it is helpful.

Comment: SystemRescueCD is great, but if you can provide some step by step instructions here, that would be even better. Just a glance at the website throws over 30 urls at you, so if you know _how_ to solve the problem, please specify it here. Otherwise the resource you provided is simply more information to the problem (a comment).